# Access Textbox content that is inside a detailsView cell

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, detailsview

Hi I need to access the contents of a textbox that is inside a details view:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transaction Name:" > 
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTransactionName" runat="server" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>            
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Tried `string v = ((TextBox)detailsNew.FindControl("txtTransactionName")).Text;` but it returned "" when I checked.
EDIT: I'm trying the above in `detailsNew_ItemInserting(...)`

Comment: Can you please post your code, where you tried this code ? Are you trying to get this in page load event ?

Comment: Updated the with the location.

Comment: I have update my answer. just try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Leaving this here to help someone else who might have the same problem.

I cannot use the sender object to get the DetailsView.
So the correct way:

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)DETAILSVIEW_ID.FindControl("TEXTBOX_ID") as TextBox;
string tmp = txt.Text;
```

DETAILSVIEW_IDis the ID of the DetailsView and TEXTBOX_ID the ID of the TextBox crated inside the DetailsView.

Comment: Is not you have specify the same thing in your question?

Comment: hum, you are right. I was probably using sender and copied and pasted something that worked and didn't try -.- and didn't even notice. I kept seeing examples that use sender.

Comment: I know this method, since you are getting issue to use this, that's why I have give you another solution. I have used both in our projects and both work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try like...

```
protected void detailsNew_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
  string v = ((TextBox)((DetailsView)sender).FindControl("txtTransactionName")).Text;
}
```

Comment: It should work, I have get this code from one of my existing project. There must be problem in somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe. I have been at this in the last two hours and can't get it to work. Maybe the way I constructed the Details View templates?

Comment: OK. I found out the error. Through the sender it simply won't work. Must put the detailsView control name. In this case details New.

Answer (score 0):

First this Item template control have to be binded with a property from your data source so that when the item inserting event is fire you can access it's data using this code

```
e.Values["ColumnName"]
```